# Capture all ionic 2 mouse events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

Is there a way to capture all mouse events (e.g. tap, scroll, etc.) in an ionic 2 App?

I am writing an idle timer which I want to reset every time the user does something in the App.

Comment: Pretty sure click works on everything since they are all about touch. If you really want to indulge Ionic uses hammer.js for all of its gesture stuff. You could try to add your own gestures that will work on everything. http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Comment: What code would I need to monitor click?

Comment: @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) on a directive http://plnkr.co/edit/EVjv3t7Z688LPzAp4MUT?p=preview

Comment: Using that code in my ionic 2 project it complains that onClick doesn't exist.

Comment: It was a cut and paste error :) Works like a charm. Thanks loads.